# Turning on vagrant server - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Yesterday I started to learn Laravel and set up server using Vagrant. Everything was fine. `example.dev` was working and even managed to make some html/css progress. Then my PC was turned off.

Today I came back home and wanted to re-start where I left but when I entered `example.dev` it said "Not found!". I went in git bash console, `cd` to vagrant and did command `vagrant up`. Machine was booted correctly and started working, but `example.dev` is still offline.

How to fix this?

I'm using Laravel 5.3 + Vagrant + VBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If webpage gives you "No input file specified." this means your project directory is not properly mounted to homestead.
first check your homestead.yaml file so it is properly formatted and has both:

```
folders:
- map: C:/your_project_root_directory
  to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

and also there should be a right settings for your nginx virtual host section

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

If your directories are different adjust accordingly.

After this settings checking you need to vagrant up --provision
It'll update your vagrant box configuration as you've specified in Homestead.yaml

this file usually placed in ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml

~ means home directory on windows it is C:\Users\Your_UserName\

after you'll provision your box make vagrant halt again and vagrant up
after this you can check if your development box accessible. To ensure you've set up path mappings correctly you can log in to  your box via ssh and check contents of /home/vagrant and subdirectories

Note: yaml files doesnot allow tab spaces! only usuall spaces edit it in editor like Notepad++ which could show you unprintable characters so you'll not break your yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and in my case I fixed by

```
  vagrant provision
```

And then

```
 vagrant up
```

Comment: Webpage after reload says: "No input file specified."

Comment: try `vagrant halt`